# Python - convert list into a table?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've written a script and ended up with a result that looks like this:

```
['chr1', '135031', '135032', 'AL627309.1_HG00276_ASE', 'G', 'A',     '19', '0', '3.81469726562e-06', '0.000153936649986637']
```

There are ten columns here. I just want to convert all of this into a table. So the output would look like:

```
    chr1    135031    135032    AL627309.1_HG00276_ASE     G     A     19    0    '3.81469726562e-06    0.000153936649986637
```

The code I tried was:

```
structure = '{:10s}' + 9 * '{:>10s}'
```

I printed that and ended up with:

```
 chr1          135031    135032AL627309.1_HG00276_ASE            G         A        19         03.81469726562e-060.000153936649986637
```

That's not a million miles off but it's not quite what I want.

Comment: Did you tried something like this [Tabultate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)

Comment: Did you try a third party module? Like this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables/3.1.0

Comment: what about `structure = '{:10s}' + 9 * ' {:>9s}'` ? (inserting a space so no fields are collated)

Comment: Your desired output has exactly four spaces between each field, while your code produces fields with fixed field width.  If you want the former, you can use `"    ".join(my_list)`.  If you want something else, you would first need to figure out what it actually is that you want.

Comment: The string before `.join` is meant to have four spaces.  It doesn't seem to be possible to have a string with multiple consecutive spaces in a comment.